# How to make WSDL.exe NOT generate the XxxAsync methods (I still want Begin/EndXxx)

Tags: .net, asynchronous, wsdl

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

See : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28VS.80%29.aspx

Play around with the parameters : "newAsync" and "oldAsync" to switch off Async methods.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!